# How to extract values from dataframe in a complicated way

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

I have a **dataframe**. I want it to filter it and reduce certain values to a string. The dataframe looks like this

[image]

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
42.0(1A,1B,0C)
41.0(1A,1B,0C)
43.0(0A,1B,0C)
45.0(1A,1B,0C)
```

**Code:**

```
data = [['42.0', 'A'], ['41.0', 'A'], ['43.0', 'B'], ['41.0', 'B'], ['42.0', 'B'],['45.0', 'B'],['45.0', 'A']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Number', 'Level'])
df = pd.crosstab(df['Number'], df['Level']).astype(str).reindex(df['Number'].unique())
s = df.add(df.columns.to_series()).agg(','.join, axis=1)
out = '\n'.join(f'{k}({v})' for k, v in s.items())
print (out)
```

**MY OUTPUT**

```
42.0(1A,1B)
41.0(1A,1B)
43.0(0A,1B)
45.0(1A,1B)
```

The solution should assume that there are three categories in the level column. The categories are A,B and C. But in the data not all the three categories maybe present. In that case it should fill in as 0 as in the below output for C category though the data didn't have C category.

Comment: run **code** and check your **output**.

Comment: What do u mean @PandaKim

Comment: I checked and not got what I want thats why I am here

Comment: I don't know why you came here and your **output** is wrong.  run your code before asking

Comment: Your data is not representative of your problem. The image shows what you want to ask about, but most people don't care about images, only code. The sample code you provided contains `['43.0', 'C']`, so all three categories are present in your output. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) In your case, I was going to say I am grateful that you provided code, unlike many others, but as Panda Kim notes, here posting both introduces more confusion.

Comment: Now I have edited sorry for that. Hope its clear now @Amadan

Comment: I have edited my code guys hope its clear now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing the `reindex` with columns

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['Number'], df['Level']).astype(str).reindex(columns = list('ABC'),fill_value=0)
s = df.astype(str).add(df.columns.to_series()).agg(','.join, axis=1)
out = '\n'.join(f'{k}({v})' for k, v in s.items())
print (out)
41.0(1A,1B,0C)
42.0(1A,1B,0C)
43.0(0A,1B,0C)
45.0(1A,1B,0C)
```